# parameter list type error in lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm not very familiar with lambda expressions C++11. I was trying to simply invoke a method from another class taking an integer and constructing a lambda expression but I'm receiving an error about the parameter not being the correct datatype.

```
class A{

  int _a;
  void f(int a){
    _a = a;
  }

};

class B{

  B(){

    A instance = new A();

    instance.f(
    [&](int input)->int
    {
      int x = 2;
      return x;
     });

  };

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? I cannot understand what you are trying to accomplish in this code. Why are you using a lambda if the function you are trying to call takes an integer?

Comment: `A instance = new A();` is not valid C++ code

Comment: The error is telling you that the function `A::f` expects to be passed an `int`, but you are instead passing it a _lambda_, which can not be converted to an `int`.

Comment: @UnholySheep who knows, maybe there's a `#define A() A*` lurking somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

A lambda is really just a compact way of writing a function.

The lambda in question:

```
[&](int input) -> int
{
    int x = 2;
    return x;
};
```

is a unnamed function, taking one `int` parameter (that it does not use)
and returning `int`. It also capture its context with reference semantics,
something it also does not make use of.

If you want to use a lambda in conjunction with a function that expects
an `int`, you need to *call* the lambda, maybe like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    void f(int a){
        _a = a;
    }
private:
    int _a;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        A instance; // = new A(); <- not C++

        auto mylambda = 
            [](int input) -> int
            {
                int x = 2;
                return x;
            };

        instance.f( mylambda(3) );
    }
};
```